# Facebook comments plugin: this feature isn't available right now

Tags: facebook, heroku, facebook-comments

I am having a problem integrating the FB comments plugin in to my website. Even when I go to the FB developer site to test, I get the error: "sorry, this feature isn't available right now". I get the same error when I try to post a comment on my own site. However, given that the bug appears on the FB developer page itself, I suspect it might not be my fault.
[screenshot of FB dev error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lb7aQ.png)

how can I fix this?

Comment: I just ran this with the URL you have in the screenshot (https://reallymeh.herokuapp.com/answer/3) and got this back from Facebook: http://i.imgur.com/uFZ6hyA.png - is that what you were looking for? Try again in incognito mode, maybe your cookies/cache are interfering with it.

Comment: Thanks @Optimae, that's not the part that fails. I can get the code and install it on my site. However, I cannot leave a comment. Can you try to leave a comment?

Comment: when I host the same code on another domain URL (website hosted by godaddy) that I own (and change the FB comment plugin configuration for this new URL), it works perfectly fine. I can use the URL and comments can be posted properly, along with other integration like comments-count, etc. It's only when I host the exact same site on HEROKU that it goes wrong. Is heroku banned from FB?

Comment: I have the same issue. comments work fine on localhost. I've tried to reset my app secret, and created a dev application in facebook console to separate the issue. Still no luck in getting comments posted to my wall. If anybody has answer to this question, i would be grateful.